# Change paper input width

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to change the width of the paper input element? I see no `width` or `size` property on the paper input that would allow for width adjustments, making this component not very usable if it is stuck at a single size.

Also, would be nice to be able to disable the error container. I had to remove it manually as it adds an extra 20 or so pixels underneath the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Add a width styling to get it o be the size you want.

I'm not at home where I can play with Polymer examples (I don't use it at work yet) so I can't post any code at the moment.

I'm assuming you're styling it in some way, so just add a width entry and size it how you want.

Comment: Adding a width attribute directly to the element's style does not change the width of the paper input

Comment: `<paper-input style="width:20em"></paper-input>` should work just fine.  You're not styling the input, but the paper-input.

go to [link](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html) and inspect one of the elements.  notice that the paper-input tags have a width:20em style applied.  take that away and they get shorter.

Comment: Does not work for me. It is possible it is because I am using them inside a core-list component. To my knowledge it does not force the resizing of its children, however, I have just started playing with the core-list.

Comment: You'll probably not want to do inline styles as a permanent solution, but the key is, unless you're making your own element, you shouldn't be styling the things inside the element directly.  Apply your style to the polymer element itself, and let the element do the rest.

Comment: Ah. I am unable to add styling directly into the element through chrome dev tools. I must add it directly into code. I assume this is because it is all painted on a canvas and it does not know it needs to re-render.

Comment: I knew there had to be some additional constraints on your problem.  If you're right about the canvas, that makes me wonder if you're able to change the width of other tags in the same scenario.  Non-polymer ones.